# How do I reference the values in a reactive variable

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to reference the values of a reactive variable. I have included the code I have so far below. I am referring to "output$var1" below. This app selects the dataset and based on that dataset produces another selectInput to select a variable.

I am able to render the text if I directly type dataset$area (the first variable of the rock dataset). I would like to render something like "dataset$selvar". Is there a way to do this?

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("dataset", label = "Dataset", choices =c("rock","pressure","cars")),
      numericInput(inputId = "obs",
                   label = "Number of observations to view:",
                   value=10)
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
      tableOutput("table"),
      selectInput("inSelect","Select variable", c("Item A", "Item B")),
      textOutput("var1")

    )
  )
  
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  datasetInput<-reactive({
    switch(input$dataset, 
           "rock"=rock,
           "pressure"=pressure,
           "cars"=cars
           )
  
    
    })
  
  
  
  
  output$summary<- renderPrint({
    dataset<- datasetInput()
    summary(dataset)
  })
  
  output$table<- renderTable({
    head(datasetInput(), n=input$obs)
  })
  
  observe({
    dataset<- datasetInput()
    varlist<-colnames(dataset)
    updateSelectInput(session,"inSelect",
                      label="Select variable",
                      choices=varlist,
                      selected=head(varlist,1)
    )  
    
    selvar<-updateSelectInput(session,"inSelect",
                              label="Select variable",
                              choices=varlist,
                              selected=head(varlist,1)
    )  
    output$var1<-renderText({
     dataset$area  
    })
    

  })
  
  
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I try dataset$selvar I get "error i ncat: argument 1 (type 'environment') cannot be bandled by 'cat'

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second `updateSelectInput` from your `observe`r, move your `renderText` outside of the `observe`r. and inside the `renderText` use `datasetInput()[[input$inSelect]]` to display the select column from the selected dataset.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("dataset", label = "Dataset", choices = c("rock", "pressure", "cars")),
      numericInput(
        inputId = "obs",
        label = "Number of observations to view:",
        value = 10
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
      tableOutput("table"),
      selectInput("inSelect", "Select variable", c("Item A", "Item B")),
      textOutput("var1")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
      "rock" = rock,
      "pressure" = pressure,
      "cars" = cars
    )
  })

  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    dataset <- datasetInput()
    summary(dataset)
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    head(datasetInput(), n = input$obs)
  })

  observe({
    dataset <- datasetInput()
    varlist <- colnames(dataset)
    updateSelectInput(session, "inSelect",
      label = "Select variable",
      choices = varlist,
      selected = varlist[[1]]
    )
  })
  
  output$var1 <- renderText({
    datasetInput()[[input$inSelect]]
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5275
```

[image]